# No module named service_account when trying to import pubsub from google.cloud

Tags: python, virtualenv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-python-api

EDIT:

The issue is that i'm trying to import from `ouath2client` pip library
BUT
I have a current module called `Whatever` who used a local version of `ouath2client` - if I try to update that `Whatever` fails.

So I want to use `ouath2client` from the `site-packages` for `pubsub` 
but the local directory `ouath2client` for `Whatever` module. 
tried like this:

```
unique_path = '/root/.virtualenvs/simple_worker/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
unique_path = '/root/.virtualenvs/simple_worker/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
sys.path.insert(0, unique_path)
from google.cloud import pubsub
sys.path.remove(unique_path)
```

But still i'm getting `ImportError: No module named service_account`

Trying to run a pub sub . getting this error :

```
  File "/proj/Backend/WorkerScripts/runRecognizerAlgo/run.py", line 748, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/app_engine_workers/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub.client import Client
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/app_engine_workers/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub/client.py", line 19, in <module>
    from google.cloud.client import JSONClient
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/app_engine_workers/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 17, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
ImportError: No module named service_account
```

relevant pips:

```
gapic-google-pubsub-v1==0.10.1
google-cloud-pubsub==0.21.0
grpc-google-pubsub-v1==0.10.1
oauth2client==3.0.0
```

checked in the `oauth2client` directory but I do see `service_account`

```
ls  /root/.virtualenvs/app_engine_workers/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/
__init__.py   _openssl_crypt.py       _pycrypto_crypt.py   clientsecrets.py   crypt.pyc           service_account.pyc  util.pyc
__init__.pyc  _openssl_crypt.pyc      _pycrypto_crypt.pyc  clientsecrets.pyc  file.py             tools.py
_helpers.py   _pure_python_crypt.py   client.py            contrib            file.pyc            tools.pyc
_helpers.pyc  _pure_python_crypt.pyc  client.pyc           crypt.py           service_account.py  util.py
```

so I don't know where the `/google/cloud/client.py` is trying to import from

When trying to import straight from the python console

```
(app_engine_workers)root@worker-test-docker-delete2:/proj/Backend/Framework/Workers# p
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.cloud import pubsub
>>>
```

then it works, weird.

Answer (score 0):

The imports in `pubsub` wont't all get evaluated at the same time `pubsub` is itself imported. They get evaluated later, at runtime, after you've already removed `unique_path` from `sys.path`.

The real problem is how to import two different versions of a Python module with the same name, which isn't something that Python would let you do without resorting to some complicated trickery. Since this is a generally bad idea anyway, the ideal solution is to rewrite `Whatever` to use the most recent version of `oauth2client`.